# A script to update time

Tags: shell, time, terminal

So, I have a script that fetches the date and time, but in standard string format. Now, when I set the date via date -s "Feb 11 2021 8:43:00" the shell allows it. But when that same string is attempted to be inserted by my script, it doesn't work and instead throws this error:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    # Automatically Updates System Time According to the NIST Atomic Clock in a Linux Environment
    nistTime=$(curl -I --insecure 'https://nist.time.gov/' | grep "Date")
    echo $nistTime
    dateString=$(echo $nistTime | cut -d' ' -f2-7)
    dayString=$(echo $nistTime | cut -d' ' -f2-2)
    dateValue=$(echo $nistTime | cut -d' ' -f3-3)
    monthValue=$(echo $nistTime | cut -d' ' -f1-1)
    yearValue=$(echo $nistTime | cut -d' ' -f5-5)
    timeValue=$(echo $nistTime | cut -d' ' -f5-5)
    timeZoneValue=$(echo $nistTime | cut -d' ' -f7-7)
    #echo $dateString
    case $monthValue in
        "Jan")
            monthValue="01"
            ;;
        "Feb")
            monthValue="02"
            ;;
        "Mar")
            monthValue="03"
            ;;
        "Apr")
            monthValue="04"
            ;;
        "May")
            monthValue="05"
            ;;
        "Jun")
            monthValue="06"
            ;;
        "Jul")
            monthValue="07"
            ;;
        "Aug")
            monthValue="08"
            ;;
        "Sep")
            monthValue="09"
            ;;
        "Oct")
            monthValue="10"
            ;;
        "Nov")
            monthValue="11"
            ;;
        "Dec")
            monthValue="12"
            ;;
        *)
            continue
    esac;
    sudo date --utc -s $monthValue.$dateValue.$yearValue
```

Which is triggering said error:

```
Date: Thu, 11 Feb 2021 22:04:03 GMT
./settime.sh: line 51: continue: only meaningful in a `for', `while', or `until' loop
date: the argument ‘9:39’ lacks a leading '+';
when using an option to specify date(s), any non-option
argument must be a format string beginning with '+'
Try 'date --help' for more information.
```

Some insight as to why that is would greatly be appreciated or any way I can automatically update the time from the terminal. Thanks.

Comment: Use an NTP daemon (or SNTP, or …) instead of this.  Your code will be slow and the time set will be inaccurate.

Comment: The message about `continue` is clear; just use `;;` in place of it.  Or omit the alternative; or report an error and exit.

Comment: You have `monthValue=$(echo $nistTime | cut -d' ' -f1-1)`, but the month name is field 4, not field 1 (which just says `Date:`).  You need `monthValue=$(echo $nistTime | cut -d' ' -f4)` (there's no real point in specifying `-f4-4` instead of just `-f4`).  Learn to debug your script: `sh -x yourscript.sh` and observe carefully what it shows.  And put an error message in your `*)` clause in your `case` statement.  (Your `timeValue` should be from field 6, not from field 5, which is also used for the `yearValue`.  Think!  Do not copy'n'paste without enough editing!)

Comment: Also consider the merits of `set -- $(curl -I --insecure 'https://nist.time.gov/' | grep "Date")` which would place `Date:` in `$1`, `Thu,` in `$2`, `11` in `$3`, `Feb` in `$4`, `2021` in `$5`, `8:43:00` in `$6`, and `GMT` in `$7`, which saves a lot of executions of `cut`, if nothing else.  Your time setting command doesn't include the time value, which is probably not what you wanted either.

Comment: I also figured out why the NTP daemon wasn't working.... I have to restart it after every time I logout or shut down for some reason. But /etc/init.d/ntp start gets it going every time. Out of laziness I simply haven't added the script to startup yet, but I will. I actually should be able to just do /etc/init.d/ntp at startup without the start.